# Part of URL adress passed as prop is not rendered in React Router

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router

I have url path: path: '/trains/:idTrain', where idTrain is passed as prop in onClick handler and idTrain is also displayed on the screen.

Main and initial screen have above path, but when I press for example "Lines" tab it still renders idTrain , as example below  "TLK12345" but it dissapears from the URL.
This is how it looks with initial render:
[image]

And once I press on any tab, like "Lines" it's like :
[image]

Here is the function how initail route is created:

```
const handlePushToTrainsDetails = (trainId: string) => {
        getTrainsDetailsData(trainId);
        history.push(
            generatePath(Routes.TrainsDetails.path, {
                idTrain: trainId,
            })
        );
    };
```

how should I implement it to have idTrain always present in the URL ?

here are routes:

```
TrainsDetails: {
        path: '/trains/:idTrain',
        name: 'Trains details',
        viewName: 'TRAINS_DETAILS',
    },
    TrainsDetailsLines: {
        path: '/trains/:idTrain/lines',
        name: 'Trains details lines',
        viewName: 'TRAINS_DETAILS_LINES',
    },
    TrainsDetailsWheels: {
        path: '/trains/:idTrain/wheels',
        name: 'Trains details wheels',
        viewName: 'TRAINS_DETAILS_WHEELS',
    },
    TrainsDetailsService: {
        path: '/trains/:idTrain/service',
        name: 'Trains details service',
        viewName: 'TRAINS_DETAILS_SERVICE',
    },
```

and here routing manager:

```
 <ProtectedRoute
                            requiredRoles={[
                                ROLES.vehicleOperator,
                                ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
                            ]}
                            isAuth={isLogin}
                            path={Routes.TrainsDetails.path}
                            Component={TrainsDetailsScreen}
                            exact
                        />
                        <ProtectedRoute
                            requiredRoles={[
                                ROLES.vehicleOperator,
                                ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
                            ]}
                            isAuth={isLogin}
                            path={Routes.TrainsDetailsLines.path}
                            Component={TrainsDetailsScreen}
                            exact
                        />
                        <ProtectedRoute
                            requiredRoles={[
                                ROLES.vehicleOperator,
                                ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
                            ]}
                            isAuth={isLogin}
                            path={Routes.TrainsDetailsWheels.path}
                            Component={TrainsDetailsScreen}
                            exact
                        />
                        <ProtectedRoute
                            requiredRoles={[
                                ROLES.vehicleOperator,
                                ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
                            ]}
                            isAuth={isLogin}
                            path={Routes.TrainsDetailsService.path}
                            Component={TrainsDetailsScreen}
                            exact
                        />
```

generatePath function below :

```
export function generatePath<S extends string>(path: S, params?: ExtractRouteParams<S>): string;
```

later on component for each path will be different

thanks !

Comment: Can you post `generatePath` and `Router` too?

Comment: post edited with routing

Comment: Can you also post the content of `generatePath` function?

Comment: added, hope it's what You are asking

Comment: Ah ok, it was react-router's function. The problem is related to `Lines` link. Can you also post the code for `Lines` link. Is it react-router `Link` or do you manually push to history?

Comment: it's react router link, please see below. Above You can find how route for lines is made
<ProtectedRoute
                            requiredRoles={[
                                ROLES.vehicleOperator,
                                ROLES.vehicleAnalyst,
                            ]}
                            isAuth={isLogin}
                            path={Routes.TrainsDetailsLines.path}
                            Component={TrainsDetailsScreen}
                            exact
                        />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238696/discussion-between-ahmet-emre-kilinc-and-marcinb1986).

Comment: fixed it , thanks